CUDA C++: Nvcc for CUDA does not allow the use of incomplete array types in variable template specialization
I am trying to port an AMD lib rocBLAS to nvdia platform. I found the statements:\
template <typename> char XXString[] = "invalid";
template <> char XXString<float>[] = "bf16_r";

It is ok for gcc C++14 to leave the compiler to determine the length of arrays. But for nvcc, although it is code of host-end, the nvcc's front-end component cudafe++ says I'm using an incomplete type.
And I'm confused that why cudafe++ bother to deal with the host codes, it seems it's gcc's duty to deal with them.
I have to change it to
template <typename> char XXString[] = "invalid";
template <> char XXString<float>[7] = "bf16_r";

Many places are left to be changed in the lib, it is a hard work. Is there a better way to solve it?

If it is host-code, it is usually a good idea to separate as much code as possible into .cpp files and compile them normally. In my projects I only use a few .cu files specifically for writing kernels and public simple C++ functions that call them and provide the interface to them. Compilation firewalls also help. nvcc has always been a bit picky and doesn't always like complex codes

I don't have any trouble compiling that code that you have shown as a .cu file with nvcc (or as a .cpp file with nvcc) from CUDA 12.2 or CUDA 12.5.  Example on godbolt

@Homer512, that used to be true, but the latest CUDA 12 has pretty good support for C++20 and I've yet to see it choke on my code (unlike, say, CUDA 9).

For a while in its development the CUDA compilers where a bit behind the times.
NVidia has made a concerted effort of late to catch up, even adding a significant chunk of std library support to the device code.
In nvcc 9.2.88 your code yields an error:

<source>:8:6: error: specializing member '::XXString<float>' requires >'template<>' syntax  
template <> char XXString<float>[] = "bf16_r";


If you switch to nvcc 10.0.130 or newer, then it compiles correctly.
See @Robert's example on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/38GEoEv5b
In general it's a good idea to not work with ancient CUDA versions, unless you need to target very old GPUs that are no longer supported in newer CUDA versions. Get the latest version that supports your hardware.
